# Git shortcut to get unmerged paths in prompt

Tags: git, shell, command-line, iterm2

During conflict resolution, I wonder if there is a way to get the **unmerged path** in the command line **prompt**.

Currently, I just use the mouse to select the file path, copy it in the prompt and just add vim, open or sublime keyword before.

Answer (score 1):

Besides copying and pasting them you can of course use tab but that is not much more effective, I would suggest to use much faster way - vim plugin [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive). It is the best and quickest way to merge conflicts I ever seen.

There are very constructive and illustrative [screen casts](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive#screencasts) available. I recommend to watch them and try everything yourself, it will get you in very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

> During conflict resolution, I wonder if there is a way to get the unmerged path in the command line prompt.

No, especially if there are *many* unmerged path.

What you *can* have in the command prompt is a notification that there are any unmerged path.

With Git 2.38 (Q3 2022), the bash prompt (in `contrib/`) learned to optionally indicate when the index is unmerged.

See [commit e03acd0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e03acd0d4ad75115f454041fac3300ae796f108f) (17 Aug 2022) by [Justin Donnelly (`justinrdonnelly`)](https://github.com/justinrdonnelly).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a572a5d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a572a5d4c1a00f276b4b6ed4e86cdb3d9aed51dc), 29 Aug 2022)</sup>

> ### [`git-prompt`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e03acd0d4ad75115f454041fac3300ae796f108f): show presence of unresolved conflicts at command prompt
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Justin Donnelly</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> If `GIT_PS1_SHOWCONFLICTSTATE` is set to "yes", show the word "`CONFLICT`" on the command prompt when there are unresolved conflicts.
>
> Example prompt: `(main|CONFLICT)`